# How can I create XSD files from M documents?

Tags: xml, xsd, data-modeling, oslo

Does anyone know of a nice way to:

1. produce XSD documents from an SQL Server Modeling Framework model
2. consume conformant XML documents using that model and add directly into the DB created from the model?

I can't see any obvious way from the current documentation, but I'm a newcomer, so I may have missed something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that would be great. I have asked for it a couple of times.
But it seems that xml-support is not in scope, not yet at least.

Most of M (the schema part) could easily translate forth and back to xsd. That would also give us the whole toolchain of xml to manage instance data and schema.

Here some forum posts and blog entries about that topic:

- Team Blog: http://tinyfinger.blogspot.com/2009/05/m-interop-with-xml-and-others.html (Still waiting for Pinky to answer :-))
- Forum Discussion: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/oslo/thread/134b2e59-b2c2-4c15-b3b7-9468afa24473

hope that helps.

-Lars

Comment: Thanks Lars, that's depressing. Is it still in scope or are they waiting for it to be done in the community?

Comment: Might be they hope for the community to do it... but we'll see. James Clark is quite involved in M... he was the technical lead of the Xml spec team, so he should be the right person to push that request.